# Update ListView from adapter Instantly

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I'm developing an application that shows stock market information. In my application I use listactivity and my own adapter is being used. 
The listView used to show the stocks is working fine and is updated with correct data. The only problem is, although I use

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the list isn't updated until scrolling and items subjected to change, are scrolled out from the screen. When they are scrolled in, they appear with new data. 
I need to change the data as soon as I notify the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have face same problem 
but finally got solution 
And its solution is

```
listView.invalidateViews();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think for that you have to take the help of the Lazy ListView or Lazy Loader:

Check out the below link :

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged in UI thread? If not: you can do the following:

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});`

Comment: still the list is changed after scrolling.

Comment: @Daniel i have same issue ... You have got any Solution for that.

Comment: @parag : list.invalidateViews(); did the trick for me, hope it works for you too.